# Make an installer for a program that appears in programs and features, creates desktop shortcuts, and can update

Tags: installation, exe

I have an executable file that I have me and all my friends use. Every time I update it they have to re-download it and move it to the correct location and update the shortcut and etc. I want to make an installer that will create a shortcut for the program on the desktop and/or start menu, add it to the programs and features list with an option to uninstall it, and to update off of a file (or files) off of my website. I can't find and program that can do all of this.

P.S. The program is written in AutoHotKey and all my friends are running windows.

Comment: You can use [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create windows installer packages - it's not super friendly, but it's very functional.

Answer (score 0):

You have the ability to build your own launcher/installer/updater in AutoHotkey. It's not an easy task but it is doable. Below is an quick outline of the program I believe you wish to write. A lot of programmer's write their problems out in pseudo code to break down a large problem into smaller parts. I don't have time to code you a full solution but maybe this will help you get started:

Outline In Pseudo Code

```
Program Start: 

Check for internet connectivity function() 
    If no Internet Skip Updater / Installer Functions Going straight to launcher

Check for .ini or Registry Entries (Where you store your installation info)
    if Information Exists and no Internet MsgBox, "Cannot install"
    Else if internet = True
        Function Installer()


Launcher: 
    Run App

Updater:
    Download Text info with MD5 Checksums
    Compare MD5 checksums to installed files
    If file different 
        function Installer(file)

Installer(file) 
    Download File
    Copy file to appropriate Directory
    Update ini or registry with MD5 of files

Md5(file, Info)
    If File = Info
        Continue

Uninstall: 
    Delete Programs / Files / Remove Directories etc
```

Below is a few functions to get you started.

Check Internet status:

```
connectedToInternet(flag=0x40) { ; Returns True or False
Return DllCall("Wininet.dll\InternetGetConnectedState", "Str", flag,"Int",0)
}
```

Usage:

```
If !connectedToInternet() {
        curstatus = False
    }
    Else {
        curstatus = True
    }
```

[URLDownloadToFiles](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/URLDownloadToFile.htm#Examples)

[MD5 Checksum](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/MD5#AutoHotkey)

Best of luck.